# How to insert selected data into new table using php mysql

Tags: php, insert-into

I need help with code on how to insert data from file "**continue_sel.php**" into another new table. Please read my attached code below. Any advice are greatly appreciated. Best Regards.

**New table format**:

**id-gdate-parlay1-gdate-parlay2-........gdate-parlay5-amount**

**Continue_sel.php**

```
<?php

include_once 'include/function_define.php';
connect();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->


<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">   </script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<div class="container">
<form method="post" action="confirm_wager.php">
<h1>GAME TIME</h1>

<table class="table  table-striped table-hover table-condensed" id="tabledata">

    <tr class="info">
        <th width=5%>No.</th>
        <th width=10%>Date: </th>
        <th>Team: </th>
    </tr>

<tbody>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['checkbox']))
{   

    echo "<br/><h4> Wager Type: PARLAY (" . count($_POST['checkbox']) . " TEAMS)</h4> ";
    $strdisplay = mysql_query("SELECT gdate, CONCAT(category, ' [', srotnum, '] ', teamname, ' ', spread) AS Parlay FROM oddset WHERE srotnum in ('".implode("','", $_POST['checkbox'])."')");
    $num_rows = 0;
    while ($strrec = mysql_fetch_array($strdisplay))
    {
        $num_rows++;
?>
        <tr> 
          <td><?php echo $num_rows ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $strrec['gdate'] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $strrec['Parlay']?></td>
        </tr>

<?php
    }

}
?>
</tbody>

</table>
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
<tr>
        <td width="70%"></td>
        <td width="30%">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>
                <div>Please Enter the amount below</div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="confirm_wager" id="confirm_wager" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
            <button type="button" name="cancel" value="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript:window.location='index3.php';" >Cancel Wager</button>
        </td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
<?php
exit();
?>
</div>
```

Comment: where you want to insert data into database??

Comment: Your question is not pretty much clear. I think you are a new comer to PHP. After following a proper online course, you would be able to understand the syntax of php. Hope this link would help you http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: @KrishnaGupta - I want to add to new table that will have these field or format. [id-gdate-parlay1-gdate-parlay2-........gdate-parlay5-amount]

Comment: @Dinidu - Yes, I am new and just lean on how to program PHP. Thank you for your advice.